# How to start pyqt ui application using systemd

Tags: service, raspberry-pi, pyqt5, systemd

I have a `pyqt5` UI application which I want to start using `systemd` service in `raspberry pi`. For this below is the service code:

```
[Unit]
Description=QT App

[Service]
User=pi
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi/Documents/qtproj
Environment=DISPLAY=:0
ExecStart=/bin/bash '/home/pi/Documents/qtproj/start_app.sh' 
Restart=always
RestartSec=10s

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

As per above code, I am starting `start_app.sh` script which loads few of the library and then finally start python3 pyqt5 application. When I am starting the above service, it stays in inactive status:

```
● myqt.service - QT App
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/myqt.service; disabled; vendor preset: en
   Active: inactive (dead)

Jul 13 09:47:57 pi systemd[1]: Started QT App.
Jul 13 09:47:57 pi sudo[7861]:     pi : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/home/pi
Jul 13 09:47:57 pi sudo[7861]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened 
Jul 13 09:47:58 pi bash[7860]: No protocol specified
Jul 13 09:47:58 pi bash[7860]: qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could no
Jul 13 09:47:58 pi bash[7860]: Could not connect to any X display.
Jul 13 09:47:59 pi sudo[7861]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed 
Jul 13 09:47:59 pi systemd[1]: myqt.service: Main process exited, code
Jul 13 09:47:59 pi systemd[1]: myqt.service: Failed with result 'exit-
Jul 13 09:48:05 pi systemd[1]: Stopped QT App
```

From the above status its clear that its not able to connect to display although I have give `graphical.target`. Can anyone please tell me how can I create a `systemd` service for `pyqt5` application. Please help. Thanks

Comment: Running a gui app from systemd is a bit odd. Do you need an ui or are you only using QtCore elements? Anyway, are you sure X has already started when the script is run? Have you read [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85244/setting-display-in-systemd-service-file)?

Comment: @musicamante If running gui app is odd from systemd, what other options I can use. Yes my qt application has UI windows. By X you mean the display, if yes then yes it has started and thanks for the link, I am reading it

Comment: It's odd because it's not what it was meant for, as *system* daemons should not rely on a graphics server (yes, X is "the display", what you can use and interact with once you've logged in; not to be confused with the boot loader "splash" image/animation). Anyway, if the solution in that link works, you should probably add your own answer to this question and mark it as accepted.

Comment: @musicamante what other options can we use?

Answer (score 0):

if it is a gui app (graphical USER interface), a logged in user is a requirement.
why not run it from a sytem wide .profile or similar for you system?

for bash that is /etc/profile.

Comment: the whole point of having a bootup pyqt application is that you don't have to authenticate and launch the script manually. So how can we avoid a "logged in user"?